# Difference of Wiener process and its relation to normal distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

One of the properties of the Wiener process is that

$$
W_{s}-W_{t} \sim \sqrt{s-t} N(0,1)
$$

where $N(0,1)$ is the standard normal distribution and the relation between the Wiener process with a random, stochastic variable $\xi(t)$ is such that

$$
W_{t} = W(t) = \int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}
$$

My question is, how do I infer the relationship of $\xi(t)$ from $W(t)$? Naively, one would think that

$$
W_{s}-W_{t} = \int_{t_{0}}^{s}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime} - \int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime} \sim \sqrt{s-t} N(0,1)
$$

I would first take the derivative with respect to $s$

$$
\partial_{s}\left(
\int_{t_{0}}^{s}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime} - \int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}\right) = \xi(s)= \partial_{s}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1))
$$

since $\partial_{s}\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}\right) = 0$. I will then take a derivative with respect to $t$ from the original equation, such that

$$
\partial_{t}\left(
\int_{t_{0}}^{s}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime} - \int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}\right) = \xi(t)= \partial_{t}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1))
$$

whereby similarly, $\partial_{t}\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{s}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}\right) = 0$. Subtracting the two equations, I have that

$$
\xi(s) - \xi(t) = \partial_{s}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1)) - \partial_{t}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1))
$$

Is this correct? I am actually quite confused and not sure what to do with the right-hand side. How does one evaluate $\partial_{s,t}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1))$?

Moreover, what should I do with $N(0,1)$? It is not a variable, it is just saying that it is a standard normal distribution with zero mean and unit variance. But if I need to calculate the correlation function/mean, namely

$$
\left<\left(\xi(s) - \xi(t)\right)\left(\xi(u) - \xi(v)\right)\right> = \left<\left(\partial_{s}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1)) - \partial_{t}(\sqrt{t-s} N(0,1)\right)\left(\partial_{u}(\sqrt{u-v} N(0,1)) - \partial_{v}(\sqrt{u-v} N(0,1)\right)\right>
$$

what should I do and how should I proceed? I think I'm not understanding $N(0,1)$ and I'm taking it a bit too literally.

Comment: $
W_{t} = W(t) = \int_{t_{0}}^{t}\xi(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}
$ is not possible. There is no such $\xi(t)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Hi there, thank you for your response. The Wiener process indeed can be defined like so. It is a bit of a misnomer, since it implies that the Wiener process is differentiable (which is not defined). In fact, this is a very common definition for the Wiener process in terms of stochastic variables. See the Handbook of Stochastic Methods for Physics, Chemistry and the Natural Sciences by Crispin Gardiner, section 4.1.

Comment: Referring to a physicist's book on questions of mathematical rigour is not a good idea. It is by no way 'a very common definition for the Wiener process' but rather a formal mambo-jambo physicists like to use. Admittetly, there is a way to introduce Brownian motion by that, using abstract white noise calculus ala Hida. But taking this as a starting point is absolutely non-instructive.